# Нужно ли брать в кавычки имя, или возможен ниже представленный вариант? Прямая речь?

Tags: пунктуация

Кевин (Kevin) – представился пригласивший, уточнив, что имя австралийское.

Answer (score 2):

Вот некоторые примеры, в которых кавычки совершенно не нужны.

— Привет! Меня Володей зовут! А фамилия Романов, как у царской семьи! – представился вошедший...

— Виктор, — прямо с порога представился вошедший посетитель и протянул руку для приветствия.

— Командующий Южным фронтом, поручик Стрелглав-Гиринейский! — галантно представился вошедший, безуспешно пытаясь щёлкнуть каблуками...

*— Александр Адельберг, — представился Сашик и представил Соню: — Софья Николаевна Ларсен.

— Соня, — представилась она и подала японцу руку.

— Коити Кэндзи, — представился японец.*
[Евгений Анташкевич. Харбин](https://books.google.ee/books?id=7PmV6tyqFj0C&pg=PT604&lpg=PT604&dq=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&source=bl&ots=1p2sGfEcss&sig=ACfU3U0zhGP8B8GCI1_vugWULkNd1S7ilg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwipsv-_mcfjAhVEU1AKHdJjDcoQ6AEwCnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%80%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%83%20%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%8F%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%86&f=false)

Про "двойного Кевина" можно написать так (скобки никак не передают речь персонажа или ее особенности; от них надо избавиться).

— Кевин, — представился пригласивший, уточнил, что имя австралийское, помялся слегка и произнес: — К-е-v-i-n. [или Ke-vin]

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае кавычки обязательно необходимы, поскольку, как Вы верно предположили, эта конструкция является прямой речью. И в данном случае мы берём в кавычки не именно имя, а подразумеваем наличие прямой речи. Таким образом, верным вариантом является следующий:

«„Кевин (Kevin)”, — представился пригласивший...»

Answer (score 0):

На прямую речь не похоже, похоже на авторский текст, и тогда ничего не нужно:

***Кевин (Kevin) – представился пригласивший, уточнив, что имя австралийское.***

Пример:

Она, протягивая руку, назвалась: Брежнева. Он мгновенно отреагировал ― представился: Сталин!  [И. Э. Кио. Иллюзии без иллюзий (1995-1999)]

Но для окончательного решения нужен контекст.

Comment: А можете дать материал по данному вопросу? Никогда не сталкивался с таким понятием, как „авторский текст”.

Comment: Авторский текст - это обычный текст, в котором дословное высказывание никак не выделяется. К примеру, как у Пушкина: Мы с удивлением спрашивали: неужели Сильвио не будет драться? Вы бы лучше у автора контекст попросили бы, тогда все было бы ясно.

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию. С такими предложениями, как Вы сейчас привели, неоднократно сталкивался, однако никогда не подумал бы, что такое возможно и в конструкциях, подобных данной.

Comment: Мне они тоже не попадались, но я посмотрела в Нацкорпусе. Почему стала там смотреть?  Просто "слова автора" показались мне странными и неподходящими для прямой речи. Они бы должны выглядеть так: представился и уточнил...

Comment: А, кажется, я Вас понял. То есть здесь смущает то, что в прямой речи должно было быть также отражено уточнение происхождения имени?

Comment: Нет, мне не нравится деепричастие совершенного вида в авторских словах.